# How to import your own HEADER (.h) file inside a C project 

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-construction, header

I am using Xcode (mac) and I want to import my own header file inside of a C project. How do I do this?

Comment: Open that file and choose `Project -> Add Current File to Project`.

Comment: Add Current File To Project is disabled

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Does `#include <C:\MyPath\MyHeader.h>` not work?

Where "C:\MyPath..." is your OS's way to specify the path.

Comment: Example fail (read again and tell me OP's OS). Also, relative paths are basically standard - for good reasons. Furthermore, if that's supposed to be a preprocessor directive (I don't know Xcode, might be some weird format it uses), strip those brackets and put a `#` in front of it.

Comment: Yes, he's using Mac, but the idea is the same, to write the header filepath within the include statement.

Comment: I used #include </Users/mbp/Apps/Testing/Math/MyHeader.h>
and it works thank u

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Strange though, that the accepted answer actually being accepted has been downvoted previously to being accepted! =P Hehehe...

Comment: @downvoters: Please, explain yourself as I don't understand being downvoted when my answer helped to solve the OP's problem. Isn't it what the OP did after all (please see his comment)!?

Comment: @Will, Perhaps using valid syntax in your example would help? Specifically, using both angles and double-quotes around the file name is incorrect. Use one or the other. And know the difference.

Comment: @RBerteig: I have perhaps made this mistake, but didn't this answer guide to the solution? I knew it was something such as what I have proposed to the OP. I haven't coded in C since about 15 years, so a bit of tolerence sometimes is to be considered. But after all, I have provided a valid solution to the OP. I think we hold to much for the details and syntax stuff than the concepts sometimes. One may have a good solution, but doesn't the EXACT syntax and he's being downvoted! Wonderful! I just don't agree with this EXACTITUDE sickness.

Comment: @RBerteig: No offense meant when I wrote the last comment. I hope one can get my point here. But most importantly, I helped the OP. Secondly, I have reminded something about the C syntax because of you, which I appreciate. Thanks for letting me know. :-) At least I know what was wrong. =)

Comment: @Will, None taken. I'm not one of the downvotes, but I thought I'd hint at what was a likely source of them. Helping the OP is indeed the point, but SO is also trying to be a reliable source. That (IMHO) means that examples should be correct in incidental details as well as helpful. We don't want to create a fresh problem while answering a question for someone new who gets here directly from Google, for instance.

Comment: @RBerteig: I guess that SO also wants we help each other. Under that point of view, I would gratefully appreciate one commenting that the syntax is incorrect, though the main idea is good, and mention what I have been doing wrong. This way, I will be pleased to have to correct my answer to show the right syntax or whatever. Anyway, I get your point, and I'm sure you got mine too. Thanks for having let me know about the syntax information. =)

Answer (score 0):

With your project open, go to the *Project* menu, choose *Add to Project...*, browse to the header file you want to add, on the next dialog click the *copy into destination group's folder* (assuming the file is NOT within your project's path), then click the *Add* button. The file will now appear within your project.